# Why does one div is moving on another?

Tags: html, css, web

As you can see below, one `div` is moving on another. How can I fix it and keep the footer on the bottom of the page? That table is made by PHP but I don't think that that would affect it. I tried to "play" with different positions but it didn't give me the correct result.

```css
.body {
  margin: 0px;
  background-image: url(../images/background.png)
}
.tbl1 {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: #000;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 4x;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.tbl2 {
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 14px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  padding: 4x;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  background-color: transparent;
}
.col-1-2 {
  width: 25%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin: 2px;
  background-color: #007dc1;
  padding-left: 6px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  border: 3px solid #005684;
}
.col-1-2-2 {
  width: 66%;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #007dc1;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  padding-left: 12px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
  border: 3px solid #005684;
}
.myButton {
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px #54a3f7;
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #007dc1), color-stop(1, #0061a7));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #007dc1 5%, #0061a7 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#007dc1', endColorstr='#0061a7', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #007dc1;
  -moz-border-radius: 6px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 6px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  border: 1px solid #124d77;
  display: inline-block;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 21px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 14px 44px;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 0px 0px #154682;
}
.myButton:hover {
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0.05, #0061a7), color-stop(1, #007dc1));
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0061a7 5%, #007dc1 100%);
  filter: progid: DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorstr='#0061a7', endColorstr='#007dc1', GradientType=0);
  background-color: #0061a7;
}
.myButton:active {
  position: relative;
  top: 1px;
}
*,
*:after,
*:before {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
[class*='col-'] {
  float: left;
  padding-right: 20px;
  /* column-space */
}
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1140px;
  min-width: 755px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.grid:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
.grid-pad {
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 20px;
  /* grid-space to left */
  padding-right: 0px;
  /* grid-space to right: (grid-space-left - column-space) e.g. 20px-20px=0 */
}
.push-right {
  float: right;
}
/* Content Columns */

.col-1-1 {
  width: 100%;
}
.col-2-3,
col-8-12 {
  width: 66.66%;
}
.tarpas {
  width: 1%;
}
.footer {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 40px;
  width: 900px;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: #007dc1;
  border-radius: 10px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}
.span {
  text-align: center;
}
.tr3 {
  background-color: #343838;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #008C9E;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.tr4 {
  background-color: #343838;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: black;
}
.reklama {
  height: 90px;
  width: 210px;
  border: 1.5px #000 solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.reklama1 {
  vertical-align: central;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 7px;
}
.linija {
  background-color: black;
  color: black;
  height: 2px;
  border: 0px none;
  clear: both;
  border-radius: 5px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.tr5 {
  background-color: #343838;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: green;
}
.tr6 {
  background-color: #343838;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: red;
}
.tr7 {
  background-color: #343838;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #009;
}
.tr8 {
  background-color: #343838;
  font-family: Trebuchet MS;
  font-size: 13px;
  text-align: center;
  color: #FF6;
}
```

```html
<a href="pirkimas.php" title="Pirkti" class="myButton">Pirkti</a>

<div class='col-1-2'>
  <h3 style='color: #FFF'>APIE MUS</h3>
  <a style='font-size: 80%;'>Daugeliui tikriausiai idomu, kas mes tokie ir ką mes galime Jums pasiulyti. „BetLt.net“ komanda sudaryta iš dideles grupes žmoniu.</a>
  <br>
  <br>
  <hr class="linija"></hr>
  <br>
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/groups/304171889786369/">
    <div class='reklama'>
      <img align="center" src="images/reklama1.jpg" height="60px" width="190px" class='reklama1'>
    </div>
  </a>
  <br>
  <br>
</div>
<div class='col-1-2-2'>
  <h3 style='color: #FFF'>PASKUTINES PROGNOZĖS</h3>

  <?php include( "lentele.php"); ?>

</div>
<div class="footer" align="center">
  <p align="center" style='text-align: center; vertical-align: middle;'>Visos teises saugomos @ 2014</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make your footer class look like this:

```
.footer {
position:relative;
float:left;
height : 40px;
width: 900px;
text-align: center;
background-color: #007dc1;
border-radius: 10px;
margin-top: 10px;
font-family: Trebuchet MS;
}
```

The result: http://jsfiddle.net/ub7rxnaa/

Answer (score 0):

As your footer is absolute positioned, it will be positioned at the bottom and it will overlap on content... try this it will work

```css
.col-1-2-2{
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }
```

Comment: It doesn't helps. The result: http://www.part.lt/img/1c4702412185d5f30e184cf875811611549.png

Answer (score 0):

You are using an absolute position for the footer, so when the container page height is less than your content page height, the footer overlaps the other divs. Is not recommended to mix absolute and relative positions with divs at the same level. Try to use float position for de divs.